# Problem with bootable usb drives

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, usb, startup

So I have just created a windows 8 bootable drive using the tutorial at http://bleeptobleep.blogspot.fr/2013/02/mac-install-windows-7-or-8-on-external.html?m=1
But when I held down the option key at startup, it only showed Macintosh HD and Recovery 10.9.2
Then, I tried plugging in the drive to a different Mac and sure enough, it worked. After holding option, it showed the usb drive as a bootable option. Does anybody know why it was not working on my other Mac?

EDIT: I fixed the issue, thank you to everyone that took the time to help me. :)

Comment: What are the differences between the two? OSX, drive type, partitions on internal volume, etc. Modify your original post accordingly.

Comment: You should try to plug the HDD while the mac is booted then go to the settings => starting disk, and see if the Win8 is shown

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer then so future visitors may benefit as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just curious, why don't you want to make a bootable USB Windows install disk with Bootcamp? Is there some compatibility issue of some sort?

Bootcamp is designed to do exactly what you want, quickly and easily **and** is installs all the Apple-specific drivers during the Windows installation.

Perhaps if we had some more details on the Mac in question and what the problem is (technical or philosophical) with Bootcamp we might be able to better assist.